# Selecting certain columns from a single row that contain @

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to extract a single row from a MySQL database table, but with certain parameters specified. The username of the row has to match what was used to login, and the variable `$groupname` must match as well. I only want to pull out data from the columns whose data contains the @ symbol (so that I know it's an email). What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT:** The table has the following rows: `id`, `timestamp`, `username`, `groupname`, and group emails labelled `ge1`-`ge10`. I want to pull out only the `ge` columns from a single row that have content.

Comment: The best way is to write a SQL-query

Comment: Posting a table structure would be appreciated.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing more about your table's definition.

Comment: @notulysses Added the table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `SQL` query to check if the `username` and the `groupname` match, and add another condition for finding some character in a string (in this example the `"@"`) after that you should parse the string in which the above constraints are met , this can be done using for loops(which is basically iterating over the string) or using recursive queries in sql , see this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0303stolze/0303stolze1.html)